# Unable to invoke aws lambda locally to debug

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rancher-desktop

Earlier I was able to invoke aws lambda locally to debug when I was using docker desktop.
Recently, I had to uninstall docker desktop due to company policy. I replaced docker desktop with Rancher desktop. After this I am not able to invoke lambda locally. I am getting exception as below.

```
undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'app'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'app'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:202:13)","    at Object.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:242:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1082:14)","    at Object..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)","    at Function._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
```

17 Feb 2022 10:10:36,503 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed InvokeID= error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 129

Comment: looks like error in your code?

Comment: There is no code change. After the replacing docker desktop with rancher desktop, I am encountering this issue.